# Weiszfeld algo for "highway" distance?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, gis, distance

The problem is to find the point minimizing the travel distance for around 100 persons in different regions who want to meet in the same place. Travel is by car not by plane.

Assuming that I get access to an API giving me mileage / kilometric distance in terms of highway travel between any two points, how can I find the best place to meet?

On other Stackexchange sites (gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65563/meeting-point-minimizing-travel-distance-for-participants) I got directed to the Weiszfeld algo to solve this problem of geometric median.

I suspect that kilometric distance complexifies the problem, because it becomes possible to get stuck in local minima. I don't know really where to start.  Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get directions (i.e., intermediate points on a shortest path) as well as distances?

Comment: Yes I can reasonably expect to get access to this info.

Comment: I see the question being put on hold. Can I clarify? The problem here is quite difficult, and there is indeed quite a gap between the existing solution for the classic problem (Weiszfeld algo to find meeting point) and the solution I ask about to a similar problem (not Euclidian distance, but driving distance). Because of this, there is no code yet because you need hints at which kind of solution wd make sense first. Moving the question to other forums? There is extensive disc. of Weiszfeld on SO, that makes it the best place to get informed advice.

Comment: Don't take it personally. There's a contingent that likes to hold-vote questions with "no code" despite the fact that software algorithms are explicitly on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it may suffer from local minima, I would try local search, since road networks aren't adversarially designed. Pick a random starting point and then iterate as follows. Compute directions from the current point to the 100 clients. Evaluate each of the next-to-last stops in the directions and move the point to the best.

Answer (score 0):

If the distances taken into account are Manhattan distances then the optimal meeting point is one of the points which has a x-coordinate equal to the x-coordinate of some input point, and the y-coordinate equal to the y-coordinate of some input point.

Comment: But this is not Manhattan distance.  Distance is highly variable between points,  depending on the presence or absence of highways  . Distance between any two points must be determined by an api call to a specialized service such as google maps or mappy.com (in Europe)

Comment: @seinecle: I'm sorry then, I don't know how to do this for a general case.